# Why won't my SP give me a useful error message?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that is returning me the very common error

```
"db_ErrorCode Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0."
```

What I've found after Googling this is that its really saying that there's an error happening before the transaction is committed.

There's a

```
BEGIN TRY            

BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

At the beginning of the SP, and

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION            

      END TRY            

   BEGIN CATCH            

  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION            

  SELECT @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),            
   @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),            
   @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()            

  RAISERROR (@Flag, 18, 120);            

      END CATCH               

END
```

The problem is is that there's about 1100 lines of code in between those lines, and if there's a problem, the entire SP needs to be rolled back, so we can't put try/catch statements in between. And why does my final Catch block not return the actual error, instead of giving me that unhelpful Transaction count error?

Comment: Try adding `set XACT_ABORT ON` to the top of the sp. This will get rid of the Transaction Count error, and should let you see the actual error.

Comment: At the top before the BEGIN TRY and BEGIN TRANSACTION, with the globals?

Comment: Yes, with the globals.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer as to why Sql Server gives the error messages it does especially not without seeing the whole 1100 lines of code. However, if you want to know what to do to be able to pinpoint the error, I can give you some hints.
First in any large stored proc I always have an @Debug variable as an input variable. Make it the last variable and give it a default Value of 0 (not in debug mode). If it has a default value then adding it as the last variable should not break existing calls of the code.

When you want to debug, you can then add tests or results that show you what steps have been completed or what the results of various operations were. Wrap these steps in if statements like

```
IF @DEBUG=1 
BEGIN
<add your tests here>
END
```

You may add this code after every significant step in the proc or maybe have a one with multiple steps in it later in the proc or both. I tend to put checks to see the state of what is going to happen in a steps through the proc and ones that show what the results should be at the end.

That code will only execute when you are in debug mode. The kind of things you might put in might be printing or selecting the variables at that point of the proc, printing the name of the step you are on, running a select that would normally be the basis of an insert or the results after after an operation, etc.

Another thing you can do is create a table variable to store the steps as they complete. Table variable stay in scope after the rollback, so you can then do a select and see what steps were completed before the rollback.